# Show curve is tangent to a surface using gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, surfaces

The question is this:
'Show that the sphere $h(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2-8x-8y-6z+24=0$ is tangent to $f(x,y,z)=x^2+3y^2+2z^2=9$ at the point (2,1,1).'

My approach was that grad(f) at P should give a normal vector to the surface f, and this should be orthogonal the sphere if it is a tangent at (2,1,1). I was thinking I could show this using the cross product. If I took grad of h(x,y,z) then it should be parallel to grad(f). grad(f) x grad(h) = (0,0,0). Can anyone confirm if that reasoning is legit?

Thanks!

Comment: $(1,1,1)$ is not a point of $f$.

Comment: And $h=0$ represents a sphere (indeed), but $f=0$ an ellipsoid; so what curve are you talking about?

Comment: Should be (2,1,1).

Comment: That's still wrong, sorry... had to fix up the equation of the ellipsoid

Comment: Could you use that the equation of the sphere can be written in the form $(x-4)^2 + (y-4)^2 + (z-3)^2 = 17$ (please check, I have been known to make some simple algebraic mistakes) and then show that the ellipsoid only touches the sphere at one point?

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct. You are given two level sets
$$h(x,y,z)=0,\qquad f(x,y,z)=9\ ,$$
both passing through the point $(2,1,1)$. Compute
$$\nabla h(2,1,1)=\ldots\ ,\qquad\nabla f(2,1,1)=\ldots$$
in order to make sure that both these gradients are $\ne{\bf 0}$. This guarantees that both level sets are indeed smooth surfaces in the neighborhood of $(2,1,1)$.

At the same time each of these gradients is orthogonal to the tangent plane of the respective surface. It follows that the two tangent planes coincide iff the two gradients are collinear. This can be verified by inspection of the coordinate values of these gradients, or by computing their cross product, which should be ${\bf 0}$.